# google map api error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have installed a theme in my wordpress everything is working fine.But there is an error while loading google map on my site i guess . I have post the error below. I tried finding google map plugin but it is not there.I couldn't find the solution web. How can i remove that plugin??

my error:

This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError

Comment: check your theme settings. If any option is there to put the google map api key. If yes try removing it

Answer (score 1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-map-plugin/ if your searching for good plugin :)  now if you want to remove the plugin first deactivate then delete the plugin from either backend or from folder dir :) hope this would help

Comment: thats the problem i can not find that google map plugin in plugin folder. Instead of that i have found a file named gmap in shortcodes folder. If i delete that there is whole pack of error showing. Eventually this plugin comes with the template and i couldn't find the proper file.

Comment: which plugin are you using? :) so you mean you deleted the shorcode folder and the plugin not working? if ur gonna use google map on custom template you should echo do_shortcode($youshortcode)  or if ur using wordpress default page system simple copy the shortcode and paste it on the the page editor and in the page.php echo the content of page  :) hope this would help